# Java, volatile and memory barriers on x86 architecture

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, memory-barriers

This is more of a theoretical question. I'm not sure if all concepts, compiler behaviors, etc. are uptodate and still in use, but I'd like to have confirmation if I'm correctly understanding some concepts I'm trying to learn.

Language is Java.

From what I've understood so far, on X86 architecture, StoreLoad barriers (despite the exact CPU instructions used to implement them) are put after Volatile writes, to make them visible to subsequent Volatile Reads in other threads (since x86 doesn't guarantee that newer reads always see older writes) (reference http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/)

Now from here (http://jpbempel.blogspot.it/2013/05/volatile-and-memory-barriers.html) I see that:

```
public class TestJIT
{
    private volatile static int field1;
    private static int field2;
    private static int field3;
    private static int field4;
    private static int field5;
    private volatile static int field6;

    private static void assign(int i)
    {
        field1 = i << 1; // volatile
        field2 = i << 2;
        field3 = i << 3;
        field4 = i << 4;
        field5 = i << 5;
        field6 = i << 6; // volatile.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            assign(i);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

the resulting assembly has the StoreLoad only after field6 assignment, and not after field1 assignment which however is volatile as well.

My questions:

1) Does what I have written so far make sense? Or am I totally misinterpreting something?

2) Why is the compiler omitting a StoreLoad after field1 volatile assignment? Is this an optimization? But has it some drawbacks? For example, another thread kicking in after field1 assignment, might still read an old value for field1 even if it has been actually changed?

Answer (score 5):

> 1) Does what I have written so far make sense? Or am I totally misinterpreting something?

I think you got everything correct.

> 2) Why is the compiler omitting a StoreLoad after field1 volatile assignment? Is this an optimization? But has it some drawbacks?

Yes, it's an optimization, but it's a pretty tricky one to get right.

Doug Lea's [JMM Cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) actually shows an example of the recommended barriers in the case of two consecutive `volatile` stores, and <s>there are `StoreLoad`s after each one of them</s> there's a `StoreStore` (x86 no-op) between the two stores and a `StoreLoad` only after the second one. The Cookbook however notes that the related analysis can be fairly involved.

The compiler should be able to prove that a `volatile` read cannot occur in the synchronization order between the write to `field1` and the write to `field6`. I'm not sure if that's doable (by the current HotSpot JIT) if `TestJIT` was changed slightly so that a comparable amount of `volatile` loads is executed in another thread at the same time.

> For example, another thread kicking in after field1 assignment, might still read an old value for field1 even if it has been actually changed?

That should not be allowed to happen, if that `volatile` load follows the `volatile` store in the synchronization order. So as mentioned above, I think that the JIT gets away with it, because it doesn't see any `volatile` loads being done.

**Update**

Changed the details around the JMM Cookbook example, as **kRs** pointed out that I've mistook a `StoreStore` for a `StoreLoad`. The essence of the answer was not changed at all.

Comment: Dimitar, you exactly got my point. :) Now, elaborating more. 
1 Could you point out where in the JMM Cookbok is the example about 2 consecutive volatile stores? I couldn't find it, even if I assumed there should be a storeload after each volatile write exactly from JMM cookbook (Inserting Barriers)
2 Your point makes much sense (JIT omitting the storeload since such field is not read anywhere). But in such case, very strictly speaking, shouldn't the final storeload be removed as well for the same reason? 
3 The "removing barrier" JMM cbook paragraph (last table row) maybe could be related.

Comment: 1. I went back to check and found out that I'm actually mistaken - I've misread a `StoreStore` as a `StoreLoad`. I'll update my answer to reflect that. 2. The quick answer here is "This is probably a specificity of the corresponding JIT". Strictly speaking coarsening the `StoreLoad`s of consecutive `volatile` stores is different than eliding the `StoreLoad` of a `volatile` store which will never be loaded. I'm not sure if the difference is meaningful enough in practice. 3. Yep, that section precisely explains the optimization being hit here, as well as the complexity of the related analysis.

Comment: after checking again the example in the cookbook (volat write STORESTORE volat write STORELOAD) which is reconducible to the code in my question, we might assume that the compiler in such cases is "sacrifying" an immediate "commit" of the first volatile change (which might not even be visible to another thread trying to read it before the 2nd volatile write in the 1st thread) to avoid 2 near expensive storeload?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the compiler omitting a StoreLoad after field1 volatile assignment?

Only the first load and the last store is required to be volatile.

> Is this an optimization?

If this is happening, this is the most likely reason.

> But has it some drawbacks?

Only is you rely on there being two store a barrier. i.e. you need to see `field1` changed before `field6` has change more often than it would happen by accident.

> might still read an old value for field1 even if it has been actually changed?

yes though you will have no way of determining this has happened, but do you want to see a new value even while the other fields might not be set yet.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question (1), you are correct with everything you've said about memory barriers etc (though the explanation is incomplete. A memory barrier ensures the ordering of ALL loads/stores before it, not just volatile ones). The code example is iffy though.

The thread performing memory operations should be ordering them. Using a volatile operation at the start of your code in this way, is redundant, as it doesn't provide any worthwhile assurances about ordering (I mean, it does provide assurances, they're just extremely fragile).

Consider this example;

```
public void thread1()
{
    //no assurances about ordering
    counter1 = someVal; //some non-volatile store
    counter2 = someVal; //some non-volatile store
}

public void thread2()
{
    flag += 1; //some volatile operation

    System.out.println(counter1);
    System.out.println(counter2);
}
```

No matter what we do on thread2, there are absolutely no assurances about what happens on thread1 - which is free to do pretty much whatever it wants. Even if you use volatile operations on thread1, the ordering wouldn't be seen by thread2.

To fix this, we need to order the writes on thread1 with a memory barrier (aka volatile operation);

```
public void thread1()
{
    counter1 = someVal; //some non-volatile store
    counter2 = someVal; //some non-volatile store

   //now we use a volatile write 
   //this ensures the order of our writes
   flag = true; //volatile operation

}

public void thread2()
{
   //thread1 has already ordered the memory operations (behind the flag)
   //therefore we don't actually need another memory barrier here
   if (flag)
   {
       //both counters have the right value now
   }
}
```

In this example, the ordering is handled by thread1 but depends on the state of flag. As such, we only need to check the state of `flag`, but you don't need another memory barrier on that read (aka, you need to check a volatile field, it just doesn't need a memory barrier).

So to answer your question (2): The JVM expects you to use a volatile operation to order previous operations on a given thread. The reason why there is no memory barrier on your first volatile operation, is simply because it has no bearing on whether or not your code will work (there might be situations where it could, but I can't think of any, let alone any where it would be a good idea).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You explained very well a valid usage of the volatile field and its happens-before guarantee as a form of synchronization. However, my example was more for reasoning on why in an experiment I had found in a blog post, the JIT compiler was acting that way (omitting a storeload after a volatile write). I agree with you that such code makes hardly any practical sense, but it's the code used in such blog to explain and illustrate some concepts, and I was just reasoning on it.

Comment: I was trying to help with the reasoning <.<. 

My code isn't intended as an example of "this is how to use volatile", but rather, as the simplest example of how the concept of memory barriers applies in practical Java. The compiler only cares about how concepts apply in practice, and conceptually; a memory barrier simply ensures that A (ie store on one thread) happens before B (ie read on another thread). I couldn't answer your question without addressing this.

Comment: but do you agree that if, for whatever reason / optimization, the compiler doesn't put a StoreLoad immediately after a volatile write, there might be a case in which another thread might see a stale value of that volatile, even if it is actually changed in the first thread? This is not breaking any happens before order, just delaying a bit the view of the updated value in other threads. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it could have implications for exactly when other threads see the value. But fundamentally, you can't translate the concept of membar to talk only about a single field/address. The concept of memory barriers refers only to the relationship between A and B, and it can't be translated to A and B independently of that relationship.